# Is `use std::io::Result as IOResult;` more efficient than `use std::io;` just to reference `io::Result` in Rust?

Tags: performance, rust, import, compiler-optimization

In learning Rust, I've seen multiple ways people import a library such as `std::io::Result`, such as:

```
use std::io::Result as IOResult;
```

and

```
pub type IOResult<T> = std::io::Result<T>;
```

However, the one I've seen probably the most and what the documentation seems to suggest is to import all of `std::io` and then reference Result in your code like `io::Result`, like this:

```
use std::io;
fn main() -> io::Result<()> {}
```

This appeals to me because it seems more immediately clear. However, I'm not sure how Rust handles imports under the hood. I'm worried that by using all of std:io, I'm importing more than I need and might be making my code less efficient, larger in size, increasing compile time, etc. Does Rust optimize this code for you? Are all of these statements equivalent in Rust or is the last approach not as efficient?

Comment: Importing a module to scope does not mean importing everything it contains, think of it as `use std::io as io`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust's `use` is not like C/++'s `#include`.

In C/++, when you `#include` something, you actually instruct the compiler to compile it. Otherwise, it may not be compiled.

In Rust, `use` is just a convenient shorthand. We can avoid it altogether - and just always use fully-qualified names (`fn main() -> std::io::Result<()>`). It does not cause the compiler to compile anything more, other than the `use` statement itself - which should add very little overhead to the program.

Glob imports (`use foo::*`), are *somewhat* more expensive because name resolution will have to look harder, but it only affects compile time in a tiny bit (so tiny you should never worry about it), and doesn't affect runtime performance at all.

Comment: So Rust's `use` is like C++'s `using`, important scoped names into the current namespace.  Like the infamous bad practice of `using namespace std;`, or things like `using std::cout;`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, it is.